# Tests return inconsistent results with static methods

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I've noticed that my Karma tests are returning a set of inconsistent results.

Often times they pass, but regularly, I get this error:

E.g. 1) should delete button element from course content if button count is more than 1

I get `Expected 3 to be 2` on the odd occasion.

E.g. 2) should not delete button element from course content if button count is equal to 1

I get `Expected 2 to be 1` on the odd occasion.

I'm testing static methods, is there a way I can guarantee consistent results?

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CourseContentElementButtonService } from './course-content-element-button.service';
import { TEST_BUILDER_INITIAL_STATE } from '../../../course';

describe('CourseContentButtonService', () => {
  const course = TEST_BUILDER_INITIAL_STATE;
  const courseContent = course.modules[0].content;
  const courseContentUid = course.modules[0].content[0].uid;
  const courseContentElementUid = course.modules[0].content[0].button[0].uid;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
  });

  describe('addCourseContentElementButton()', () => {
    it('should add button element to course content', () => {
      const newCourseContent = CourseContentElementButtonService.addCourseContentElementButton(
        courseContent,
        courseContentElementUid,
        courseContentUid
      );
      expect(newCourseContent[0].button.length).toBe(2);
    });
  });

  describe('deleteCourseContentElementButton()', () => {
    it('should delete button element from course content if button count is more than 1', () => {
      let newCourseContent = CourseContentElementButtonService.addCourseContentElementButton(
        courseContent,
        courseContentElementUid,
        courseContentUid
      );
      expect(newCourseContent[0].button.length).toBe(2);
      newCourseContent = CourseContentElementButtonService.deleteCourseContentElementButton(
        newCourseContent,
        1,
        courseContentUid
      );
      expect(newCourseContent[0].button.length).toBe(1);
    });
    
    it('should not delete button element from course content if button count is equal to 1', () => {
      let newCourseContent = CourseContentElementButtonService.deleteCourseContentElementButton(
        courseContent,
        1,
        courseContentUid
      );
      expect(newCourseContent[0].button.length).toBe(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I suspect the issue with this is the line `const course = TEST_BUILDER_INITIAL_STATE;`. In this case all of your tests will refer to the same instance of `TEST_BUILDER_INITIAL_STATE`, and as they change it in a random order, it may not be what you expect it to be. Fix for this is to put a `let course;` statement where that const is, and then assign it to a *clone* in `beforeEach`, ie with lodash's `cloneDeep` or a similar tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Jasmine (which you didn't specify in question, but it is by far most common in my experience) - by default the order of tests is randomized. And you don't reset the state before each test. Meaning there is 1/3 chance that addCourseContentElementButton will run before the other methods.

You can either ensure your tests are not state-dependent (i.e. don't depend on execution of other tests) or, if in you case they should be executed in order, disable random order.

Config options for jasmine can be found [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.3/Configuration.html).